# Is it possible to stack line graphs with df.plot() and if not how can it be done?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I want to create something like this figure with a dataframe that contains  9 columns.

Comment: Please show us the data and your tried attempts so far. By the way, these plots are called Area plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the area type:

```
df.plot(kind='area')
```

Starting pandas version 0.17:

```
df.plot.area()
```

Comment: using modern pandas versions it's recommended to do it this way: `df.plot.area()` ;)